# What's the difference between plane separation and decision boundary in a support vector classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I just began learning the main ML algorithms and started with supervised learning. The course im at keeps describing the *plane separation* as the vector (2D example)and the decision boundary as the separation between the two categories.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Plane separation is not known to me as a standard term. I would guess that in this case it used to denote the separating plane. In your 2D example, this would be the line (a 2D plane) separating the classes.

In the case of a linear SVM the separating plane is usually also your decision boundary. Although you can also vary a so called decision threshold and thereby move that plane to parallel positions. For the non-linear SVM the decision boundary is not generally represented by a plane anymore, but can have more complex shapes, such as curves and so on.

Comment: So the orange line is both cause it's a two dimensional plane. And with hyperplanes (multidimensional) it's another story. Thanks dude!